# Django filter __in returns first match instead of all

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Location` with a field `tag`:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

In my code I have a list of tags read in from a file:

```
in_tags = row['tags'].split(',')
```

which creates `in_tags` having the value `['GB_31', 'GB_32', 'GB_33']`

My query looks like this:

```
location_set = models.Location.objects.filter(tag__in=in_tags)
```

It's returning a QuerySet with only one location object, the one with tag='GB_31'.

I've tried removing the first element, in case the other tags were missing or malformed, and it again returned only the first match.

I went into the database and executed the query

```
SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `tag` IN ('GB_31', 'GB_32');
```

It returned both locations, as expected.

I'm running django 1.9.2 with python 3.4.4

Comment: How do you know the returned QuerySet contains only one object?

Comment: You specify that the value you want to query by is defined as `in_tags`, yet you are querying by a variable called `location_list`. Was this just a typo in the question, or is that discrepancy in the actual code as well? According to the question, as written, you are not querying by the three values in `in_tags`

Comment: `Django 9.2`? I must have slept too long...

Comment: Is `location_list` the correct variable in the query. Your other names indicate you might have to use `in_tags`?

Comment: The location_list is what's actually in the code. I renamed it for clarity then forgot to adjust the second instance. Editing to correct it.

Comment: @Blender, I'm using PyCharm, so I can set breakpoints and look at the contents of all the variables. I also have a check for each location being found, and I see the errors in my log.